# Should I override a template for a Django (comments) framework or do the customization inside my own templates?

Tags: django, django-templates

I am trying to customize the output of the comments list and forms using [Django's comments framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/comments/).

Inside my own template, should I try to customize the comments by doing something like `{% get_comment_form for object as form %}` and carefully construct the form based on the `form` variable or should I override the `form.html` template and simply call `{% render_comment_form for object %}`?

Currently I'm leaning more toward using `{% get_comment_form for object as form %}` inside my own template, but using `form.html` as a guideline to write my own form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my websites, overriding form.html (and other comments templates) and simply calling `{% render_comment_form for object %}` **works very well**.

**You should definitively have a form.html that is customized for your website's design**. And *in case* you want a comment form to have a particular design, you can use `get_comment_form`.